# Can somebody help me to understand what is happening with this traceroute?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, traceroute

The internet on my laptop continually disconnects randomly. I stay connected to the wireless network but lose access to the web. I suspect it may have something to do with my Pi-hole which is also the DHCP server. I have provided traceroute output below... This only happens to my linux xubuntu laptop, no other devices are affected at all.

I'm no networking genius but it looks like xubuntu is looking for a local IP address and this is causing the problem....

Have tried changing the DNS address in resolve.conf but that did nothing.
Have read this could be an Ubuntu bug....

Manually disconnecting from the wireless and reconnecting resolves the issue temporarily.

When I have internet available:

```
traceroute to google.com (216.58.203.110), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.0.1  2.488ms  1.880ms  1.867ms 
  2   10.205.144.1  13.783ms  9.947ms  9.793ms 
  3   58.160.250.129  10.620ms  10.012ms  17.399ms 
  4   203.50.44.36  10.580ms  14.939ms  9.040ms 
  5   203.50.11.136  10.695ms  17.102ms  10.642ms 
  6   203.50.11.180  22.117ms  21.678ms  22.953ms 
  7   203.50.11.177  20.487ms  19.407ms  19.879ms 
  8   74.125.49.138  22.451ms  26.402ms  23.768ms 
  9   *  *  * 
 10   74.125.37.200  23.455ms  24.230ms  23.549ms 
 11   108.170.247.59  24.866ms  21.415ms  21.855ms 
 12   216.58.203.110  24.224ms  20.593ms  20.140ms 
astroboy@inspiron:~$
```

When the internet is not available:

```
astroboy@inspiron:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (198.18.1.1), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.0.1  1.864ms  1.805ms  1.719ms
  2   10.205.144.1  14.747ms  8.589ms  11.015ms
  3   58.160.250.129  11.417ms  10.130ms  10.348ms
  4   203.50.44.36  9.546ms  12.165ms  10.650ms
  5   *  *  *
  6   *  *  *
  7   *  *  *
  8   *  *  *
  9   *  *  *
 10   *  *  *
.......
 64   *  *  *
```

Any help troubleshooting would be hugely appreciated!

```
Details:
Dell Inspiron 5000
Linux Xubuntu 18.04 LTS
ISP: Telstra (cable)
RPi running pi-hole as DHCP - version 4.3.1
Disabled DHCP on wireless router
```

Comment: This looks like a DNS problem.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: It's funny but I experience exactly the same problem on ubuntu 20.04. `resolvectl status` shows expected DNS servers, and asking those directly resolves hosts as expected. Yet just `dig google.com` (or effectively _any_ hostname) returns `198.18.1.1`